# How to undo integration of Sharepoint site with Groups?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I will try to explain my sharepoint issue as best I can.

My company asked me to play around with one of the company SharePoint sites to see if it was possible to establish on the site a common unified calendar that everyone could share events on and which was connected to outlook. I read that on SharePoint you can do this through use of Groups so I went to "Connect an Office365 Group to site" feature and created a private group to see how it works.

This created a new modern home page but not just for the members of the private group, but for EVERYBODY that has access to that SharePoint site. This was not my intention to change the homepage of the sharepoint site, I was just playing around with the functionality seeing what groups can do.

The issue now is they asked me to take it down and I don't see a way to disable this group (of 2 people) so the homepage goes back to how it was before, unless I delete the group. But I am afraid deleting this group will also delete the SharePoint site it's connected to...which would be a big problem.

What can I do?